# Finding the Surface area of body $T(B)$

Tags: calculus

Let $B = \{(x, y, z) | 0 ≤ x, y, z ≤ 1\}.$ $B$ is in fact the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Let $T$ be the linear transformation that is defined by $T(x, y, z) =
(2x − y + z, x + y + z, x + z)$, find the surface area of the body $T(B) =
\{T v | v ∈ B\}.$

I tried to understand the shape of the body by using $x' , y' , z'$
and the equation was $x' - y' + 3z' = z$  and $z$ should be between $0$ and $1$.

If I am right how could I continue?

Reference : technion institute of technology .

Answer (score 1):

Just by looking at the form of $T$, you notice that is just a linear transformation. That means that you have a cube that is rotated/scaled/skewed. Since there are not extra constant terms, it means that there is no translation.

You have $(0,0,0)$ unchanged. Now transform corners adjacent to it:
$$T(1,0,0)=(2,1,1)\\T(0,1,0)=(-1,1,0)\\T(0,0,1)=(1,1,1)$$ 
These three sides form three parallelograms. The area is given by the cross product. The total surface is twice as large as the sum of these three (we have three other parallelograms, with the same area).

Comment: Just for exercise, calculate the other corners. Prove that you indeed have parallelograms. For example, show $T(1,0,1)-T(0,0,1)=T(1,0,0)-T(0,0,0)$

Comment: thank you for helping out now its much clearer

Answer (score 0):

To get you started: the cube has $8$ corners. Calculate the image of each of those corners. They will make a parallelepiped. Each of the six faces will be a parallelogram. You can find the areas of those faces with ordinary geometry.

For example, $T(0,0,0) = (0,0,0)$ and  $T(1,0,0) = (2,1,1)$. If you find $T(0,1,0)$ and $T(1,1,0)$ you will have the four corners of a parallogram. Then you can find the angles and the lengths of the sides. That is enough information to calculate the area. You can look up how to do that with a web search. You can also do it with the cross product.

Comment: how can i calculate the image of a corner

Comment: lets asume i caclulated the new angels how could i get the length , width .. of the body , i tried to use plane equation to get all those details but it didn't work

Comment: @RaziAwad See my edit. You have to tell us just what "didn't work" in order to get help fixing it. Don't do that in a comment, Edit the question to show us everything you did until you got stuck.

Comment: thank you i'll try my best.